# How to copy bundled realm database with some data to access it in my app?

Tags: android, database, realm

I'm developing an app something like phone contacts. And I need to provide a database with all the data to use it in my app in offline.

I prepared a database file in my OSX app that I wrote specifically for this task (is there some real client to create realm files?) And I use this database in my iOS app. I just copy the file from bundle and connect to it using Realm.Configuration. All works fine.

Now I'm trying to do the same for android.

- I put the file into `raw/databasefile.realm`.
- Implemented function `copyBundledRealmFile` as in the migration demo app on GitHub repo.

Then create RealmConfiguration:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .name("databasefile.realm")
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
```

and init realm:

```
realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

After that I see that the realm is empty. Why?

Comment: Perhaps the `deleteRealmIfMigration` flag was triggered which reset the Realm file. Have you tried not having that configuration enabled?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior it says "RealmMigration must be provided”. But there is no old database on the device. Why do I need migration?

Comment: because of your RealmObjects declaration might be different from what you have when create the db. Can you please built the config with an empty migration, remove the `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` then see what is the migration needed exception message? It will tell what is the diff between the RealmObjects you defined and those in the realm file.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like I made a wrong RealmObject subclass. Just realised that it is possible to save model definition from the RealmBrowser.

and now it works.